# Deploy a swagger generated RESTFUL API in websphere 8.5

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, websphere-8

I have created a REST Spring-MVC webservice using swagger plugin for maven. Here is the plugin definition and goals in my pom:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-spring-mvc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <language>spring-mvc</language>
                        <modelPackage>com.myproject.ws.gen.model</modelPackage>
                        <apiPackage>com.myProject.ws.gen.api</apiPackage>
                        <templateDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../templates/JavaSpringMVC</templateDirectory>
                        <configOptions>
                            <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-yaml-dist</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <language>swagger</language>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/site/api</output>
                        <addCompileSourceRoot>false</addCompileSourceRoot>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The plugin takes then the api.yaml file, wich contains the definition of the API and generates the java code with spring annotations, additionally, I am using CORS filter to manage the requests. 
When I deploy the war in a Websphere Liberty profile server, all runs ok, but when I try to do the same in a full WebSphere 8.5, I always get "File not found" massage from server.

I have checked that the application is installed correctly and the generated .class files of the REST API are packaged in the .war and also that the request is processed by the CORS Filter, but for some reason it still does not work.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer, not edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the difference is in the CORS support, or misconfigured CORS support.

In [WebSphere Liberty](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_webcontainer_cors_config.html) the support is configured in the server.xml using the cors tag.

In WebSphere Traditional 8.5 you may need some JAR file additions as described [here](http://clmpractice.org/2015/01/07/how-to-enable-cors-with-rational-team-concert-ccm-running-on-a-websphere-application-server-was-8-5/) along with the relevant app configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I had alredy try this. The only thing I can not do is enable CORS in the webapp because I do not have front end. My app consist only in a REST web service.
However, I have try the test-cors web site and I have got the same result, "File not found" So it is possible that the problem is in CORS configuration, or CORS integration with WAS 8.5 but i do not know how to solve it.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a standard JEE servlet filter then it should work on both Liberty and WAS traditional.  It doesn't seem like you're using Liberty's native CORS configuration, so I am assuming a regular servlet filter.

Have you tried accessing your endpoint from a client that doesn't trigger CORS (ie: java client), to ensure that the application is indeed running and accessible in your WAS traditional environment?   A manual CORS filter should *always* work, without special configuration besides actually registering the filter with your app.